# How to convert special character to Image(Smiley)

Tags: android, web-services, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [webserivce messages in listview with smileys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537345/webserivce-messages-in-listview-with-smileys)

I created a Db and added 4 fields to it. 1. ID , 2. Position, 3. Special Character 4. URL. So I was able to display the corresponding special character when clicked. when I submit how can I convert that special character into smiley image. I tried to use functions like "Contains()" and "Replace". But nothing worked when I submitted the message to list view.

I am listing messages in list view from web service.

I get the same special character and text. I don get the image instead of special character.

How can I convert special character into smiley image. I store all the images in drawable folder.

Comment: use canvas to draw text and save it as a bitmap. So the text will be changed as bitmap.

Comment: I need to convert special character into smiley image stored in drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

First Thing :Using ListAdapter you can achieve this
Refer : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

And Second : You need to programatically decide which icon to replay with which special character.

In List Adapter you will have textview + icon.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use the webview. And create a html string and replace your special characters with image tags.