# Contains and Replace string with image in android

Tags: android, web-services, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [webserivce messages in listview with smileys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537345/webserivce-messages-in-listview-with-smileys)

How can i replace string with image coming from .net web service in android.

I get data as  hi :). i need to replace that special charcter to corresponding image that s available in my drawable folder.

How can i achieve that. I have tried with contains and replace. But it was of no use.

Kindly guide me in this issue .

Thanks.

Regards,
Raghav Rajagopalan

Comment: This is the 4th similar question. Flagged and downvote. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537345/webserivce-messages-in-listview-with-smileys

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called [ImageGetter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html). You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792604/html-imagegetter)

Comment: in chat application i need to display smileys along with text in list of messages. How can i do is my exact question. I have a list view where i display all my incoming message from web service. while fetch data i need to replace the data and while data is displayed i need to show text with smiley. What should i do to achieve that.